# Why double equation doesn't work when evaluating the value?

Tags: bash, shell

I am wondering why this doesn't work:

```
$ echo "$((256 & 0xff != 0))"
0
$ echo "$((256 & 0xff == 0))"
0
```

But this seems working:

```
$ echo "$((4 & 0xff))"
4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` has higher [precedence](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html) than `&`. Add parentheses:

```
$ echo "$(((256 & 0xff) != 0))"
0
$ echo "$(((256 & 0xff) == 0))"
1
```

Comment: weird. Why on earth would `==` have higher precedence than bitwise operators?

Comment: Good question. See [Why do bitwise operators have lower priority than comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194635/why-do-bitwise-operators-have-lower-priority-than-comparisons)